# Upgrading, received database error

Tags: upgrade, database

On a (copy of a) Drupal 7.92 site, I'm attempting to upgrade CiviCRM from version 5.42.1 to 5.55.2.  I did this by executing the following steps:

```
cd /bitnami/drupal/modules/contrib
rm -rf civicrm
curl -L https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.55.2-drupal.tar.gz | tar -zxf -
```

and then (since I don't have `drush` installed) I visited `/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1` on my site to execute the database updates.  Everything seemed to go well (there were a lot of updates!) until just before the end of the progress bar, when I got this error message:

[image]

It doesn't give any more specifics than this, e.g. what constraint is being violated.

If I visit the `/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1` upgrade page again, it says "Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 5.55.2".

Can I assume that this is not going to cause any snags?  Any way to figure out more specifically what went wrong, before I try this on my live site?

**UPDATE**

@pradeep-nayak correctly suggested that there were likely CiviCRM Extensions that needed to be updated.  Here's a screenshot of my extensions page after attempting the upgrade:

[image: extensions page]

I'll try doing the upgrade in steps as suggested and update if anything *interesting* happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an Extended report extension installed? If yes, then probably you would need to

1. Upgrade CiviCRM to 5.46.3
2. Upgrade the Extended report extension to the latest version.
3. Upgrade CiviCRM to 5.55.2
4. Run the extension update db if there are any.

or

1. Replace the extended report extension folder to latest.
2. Upgrade CiviCRM to 5.55.2
3. Run the extension update db if there are any.

Comment: Oooh, indeed there's a ton of stuff in Extensions that says it needs updating.  I'll post a screen shot of that as an addendum to my question, looks like this might be a multi-step process.  I'm super glad I'm practicing on an AMI on AWS so I can keep scrubbing it and start over.

Comment: First, sort the missing extension and later update the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pradeep-nayak for setting me on the right path.  For posterity, here are the steps that ended up working.

```
# DO: visit /civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 and do updates


# Upgrade drupal
DRUP=~/stack/drupal
TB=drupal-7.92.tar.gz
OTHER=/bitnami/drupal

sudo mv $DRUP $DRUP-old

cd "$(dirname $DRUP)"
curl https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/$TB | sudo tar -zxvf -
sudo mv "${TB//\.tar\.gz/}" drupal

cd $DRUP
sudo rm -rf sites
sudo ln -s $OTHER/sites .
sudo ln -s $OTHER/modules/contrib $DRUP/modules/



# Upgrade civicrm to intermediate version
V1=5.46.3
cd $OTHER/modules/contrib
rm -rf civicrm
curl -L https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-${V1}-drupal.tar.gz | tar -zxf -
# DO: visit /civicrm/upgrade?reset=1
# DO: visit /civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 and do updates


# Upgrade civicrm to final version
V2=5.55.2
cd $OTHER/modules/contrib
rm -rf civicrm
curl -L https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-${V2}-drupal.tar.gz | tar -zxf -
# DO: visit /civicrm/upgrade?reset=1
# DO: visit /civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 and do updates
```

When I did this "for real" the final time, I did get some errors in the website after the CiviCRM steps about various PHP errors that prevented the site from loading.  I'm not sure what that was about, but just waiting a while longer between steps seemed to cure it.